# synchronizing bitbucket repo

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, tortoisehg

I'm working in a project whose repo is hosted in bitbucket. Recently one of the collaborators issued a commit that changed a lot of files in the repo, my connection is very slow (256kb/s and shared), and from that point on I haven't been able to download the changes in the repo. The situation is so critical that the Tortoise hg workbench could not even finish to check the incoming changes. I have tried to clone the repo from the beginning and nothing either.
One thing that I did accomplish (with a lot of effort) was to download the repo as a zip archive from the bitbucket site. Now I have all the repo files locally but if I create a new repo with those files and sync with the bitbucket repo the situation is worse because they are different repos from the point of view of hg.
How can I say to hg to sync the online repo with the one I have locally and make it understand that what I have is part of the original repo? Is that possible?

On the other hand, is there a method by which I can pull the changes in the bitbucket repo with some kind of resume capability in such a way that I can continue the download from the point it was interrupted if the connection lose?

Comment: You are going to need to go lower level than tortoise hg. You are likely going to need to use the mercurial command line tools to deal with this. At least that is my guess.

Comment: i had a very similar problem using a hotel's wifi once. my absolutely terrible, yet functional, solution was make myself an amazon aws micro instance, ssh into it, do my hg clone from there, then tar up the cloned repo and scp it onto my laptop and then delete the micro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't closed this question that is from long time ago, but the fact is that I'm new in stackoverflow and did not know the way around here.

Any way the solution I found to this problem in those days (more than 4 month ago) was to connect to bitbucket ussing ssh instead of https and then wait a lot of time for the changes to download, but at the end they did it.

This solution was not exactly the same proposed by frymaster but that was the one that inspired me to look into ssh.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a single changeset that's causing the problem there may not be much you can do.

However, if it's multiple changesets you can download them one-by-one.  Use the web interface to find the commits after the latest one and do `hg pull -r changeset-id` using successive changeset IDs until you have all the new code.